# How to deploy Node CLI utility app, general question

Tags: node.js, deployment, command-line-tool

My app in a nutshell: It is a CLI app. It does mini helper tasks. It intakes keywords into the console such as 'search' & opens a new tab with the search query, or 'definition' and pulls a definition from the dictionary and logs the results to console, 'email' opens thunderbird, etc...

I have uploaded this to Heroku, and it is a successful deployment. BUT, how do I access all of the CLI inputs (process.stdin, process.stdout) that I use when I run it on local host in windows terminal?

Comment: Is this CLI embedded into web page? Could you please provide more details. I dont understand what is the relation between CLI and Heroku

Comment: @Evgheni Calcutin - I only bring up Heroku since it is a free platform to deploy to and therefore make the app accessible via the web. What I am not understanding is, how or where do I deploy a command-line based app that can be accessed via the command line on the web, so that the apps features may be used.
To answer your first question, the CLI interface is not embedded into the web page.

Comment: Could you please provide that heroku app ulr or screenshot? Also, you might contact me on telegram @ecalcutin so we can edit your question and I will able to help you